# opencv: stitch images together

Tags: opencv

I am trying to stitch two images together, but only the first one can bee seen in the final image.
Here's my code:

```
Mat result(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3);
Mat firstPart = result(Rect(0, 0, image1.cols, image1.rows));
Mat secondPart = result(Rect(deltaX, deltaY, image2.cols+deltaX, image2.rows+deltaY));
image1.copyTo(firstPart);
image2.copyTo(secondPart);
imshow("result", result);
```

image2 is only visible in the result, if deltaX and deltaY are zero and I can't figure out why (image2+deltaX < 1000, same for deltaY).

Comment: did you check if image2 is copied over image1? If that is the case you have to copy image2 with offset to result

Comment: yes, I commented image1 out. With deltaX and deltaY set to 0, image2 is shown in the top left corner, with one of them unequal to zero it is not shown.

Comment: try commenting image2 out and see if there is image1 in the result and post back.

Comment: there is always a possibility that result image isnt big enough to store image1 and 2

Comment: I just tried it again, to be sure :)
deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;
Mat secondPart = result(Rect(deltaX, deltaY, image2.cols+deltaX, image2.rows+deltaY));
image2.copyTo(secondPart);
imshow("result", result);
works fine, if I set deltaX = 1, result is empty/black.

Comment: shouldnt it be something like this: secondPart = result(Rect(image1.cols, image1.rows, image2.cols, image2.rows)) ? did you check result2 is big enough to hold image1.row+image2.rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from android I assumed the parameters of Rect would be left, top, right, bottom, but they are left, top paired with width and height. Therefore it has to be

```
Rect(deltaX, deltaY, image2.cols, image2.rows)
```

instead of

```
Rect(deltaX, deltaY, image2.cols+deltaX, image2.rows+deltaY)
```

.